# How to pull emails from Outlook to Excel starting with the most recent email?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

My code takes account of the date of the email versus my threshold. For example, if I set my threshold to 4/1/2020, it will put all emails from 4/1/2020 to today.

My code is slow because it starts with my oldest email. How do I start the indexing with the most recent email?

The code I found online using items.sort "CreationDate", true doesn't work because it removes the date completely.

I've simplified the code:

```vb
Sub dateextract()
    Dim OutlookApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim Outlooknamespace As Namespace
    Dim folder As MAPIFolder
    Dim subfolder As MAPIFolder
    Dim OutlookMail As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim dates As Date
    Dim time As Date
    Dim sender As String   
    
    Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set Outlooknamespace = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set folder = Outlooknamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    dates = Cells(1, 2).Value
    i = 1
    
    For Each OutlookMail In folder.Items    
        time = OutlookMail.ReceivedTime
        If time >= dates Then

       '........
```

Comment: Why do you have such an extremely amount of emails in your inbox? Of course it takes time. I doubt that the inbox is a database where you can use SELECT. Thus Outlook needs to loop through all emails in your overcrowded inbox. Solution? Clear your inbox and start over. An alternative is to export the inbox and process all emails locally.
Hint: At the end of the day, the inbox is empty! Do you store your physical mail envelopes in your physical mailbox? Nope!

Comment: That doesn't help me. For my purposes I need my entire inbox to be searchable. And the idea is if I can start with the newest emails, I can add an if statement that ends the for loop if it goes beyond the threshold

Answer (score 1):

Restrict and sort is the usual solution.

```vb
Sub dateextract()

    ' Early binding
    '  Reference Outlook XX.X Object Library
    Dim outlookApp As Outlook.Application
    
    Dim folder As folder
    
    Dim outlookItem As Object
    
    Dim i As Long
    Dim dates As Date
    
    Dim fldrItems As Items
    
    Dim strFilter As String
    Dim resItems As Items
    
    Set outlookApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set folder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    
    ' Unknown value and unknown format
    'dates = Cells(1, 2).Value
    
    ' dates = Format("2020-01-04", "yyyy-mm-dd")    '?
    dates = Format("2021-01-04", "yyyy-mm-dd")
    
    Set fldrItems = folder.Items
    Debug.Print "fldrItems.Count: " & fldrItems.Count
    
    strFilter = "[CreationTime] > '" & dates & "'"
    Debug.Print strFilter
    
    Set resItems = fldrItems.Restrict(strFilter)
    Debug.Print "resItems.Count: " & resItems.Count
    
    ' Sort collections in memory, not items in folder
    resItems.Sort "[CreationTime]", True
    
    For i = 1 To resItems.Count
        If resItems(i).Class = olMail Then
            Set outlookItem = resItems(i)
            Debug.Print i & ") " & outlookItem.CreationTime & ": " & outlookItem.Subject
        End If
    Next
    
End Sub
```